# Mac -> Windows Remote Desktop Keyboard [German Layout]

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

I thought, that instead of a VM on my MacBook, I would just RDP to a Windows Server, and write my code there (C#,Visual Studio).
Problem is that the keyboard mapping is completely wrong:
What I'd want is to have the normal Mac keyboard layout (German) in the Remote Desktop session too.
Now i downloaded a keyboard layout and installed it on windows, BUT as the a lot of keys are mapped to ALT+NUMBER (like ALT+5 for [ and ALT+6 for ]) and windows' default behaviour for the alt key is, to highlight the menu, i can't work with that mapping.

Would anyone of you have an idea to get that working?

I'm open to all suggestions and tried googling for some hours without finding a good solution

Thanks

Comment: Note: Pressing alt+ctrl and then a number,it works as it should, but as there is no ctrl key on the right side of the keyboard, it's not really convenient

Comment: Have you tried to customize the keyboard behavior in the Preferences of Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection for Mac ? You could also try [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) - a Mac RDP client for Windows computers.

Comment: i tried CoRD but it performs really badly compared to the normal remote desktop, even at the lowest possible settings.
Customizing the keyboard behaviour i could only manage to disable forwarding the alt key at all, but if you have any idea to get it working, that would be great

Comment: If you can't tackle it on the Mac side, you could map the keys on the Windows side. The best utility for that is [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: That would also mean, that i'd always have to start the tool when i'm on the mac and stop it when i'm on a pc. of course,it's an option, but shouldn't there be a better approach?

Comment: AutoHotkey is such a versatile tool that it could probably verify the context of the session and act accordingly - whole products have been written entirely in AutoHotkey. But I don't have the time to research all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by harrymc i'm using an AutoHotKey script right now

```
!5::[
!6::]
!7::|
!8::{
!9::}
!n::~
```

i'm still trying to get the auto-run feature of RD working, so it automatically starts the program upon connecting.

Might not be the most elegant solution to this problem, but at least it works and i can easily change the script

Answer (score 0):

According to [this VMware KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005578), installing Boot Camp drivers on Windows also adds Apple / Mac versions of some keyboard layouts as options in the control panel.